# JavaScript: Looping through an array of objects and filtering specific properties/attributes

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, filter

I'm trying to loop through an array and return just the addresses and the number of packages and then having the total number of packages in the array added up. Problem is, when I write this all in codepen.io, it tells me that each name attribute is having an unexpected identifier error. I know I'll have to work on the loop itself but what is wrong with this? Here is what I'm seeing in Codepen.io and here is the link if you want to see what codepen is showing: https://codepen.io/epbutterfield/pen/NBxMQb?editors=0012

I know it's super simple but I must have an extra identifier or am missing one....

```
var deliveryItinerary = [
  {  
    name: Doctor Allen Grant,
    address: '123 Jurassic Park Trail, Kualoa Ranch, Hawaii',
    zipcode: 96744,
    packages: 5
  },
  {
    name: Harry Potter,
    address: '4 Privet Drive, Manchester, England',
    zipcode: 81726,
    packages: 8
  },
  {
    name: Bowen Knight,
    address: '1600 Camelot Court, Liverpool, England',
    zipcode: 15064,
    packages: 2
  },
  {
    name: Van Helsing,
    address: '1462 Dracula\'s Castle, Valerious, Transylvania',
    zipcode: 18870,
    packages: 1
  }
];

for (i = 0; i < deliveries.length; i++){
  console.log(deliveryItinerary[i].address)
  console.log(deliveryItinerary[i].packages){
    deliveryItinerary.reduce[i].packages
  }
};
```

Comment: `{ name: Doctor Allen Grant,` Strings need to be enclosed in parentheses.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Okay cool! I did that but it is still saying I have an unexpected identifier unfortunately

Comment: @CertainPerformance Oh wait... I totally forgot the quotes to show it was a string haha. That fixed that!

Comment: `console.log(deliveryItinerary[i].packages){
    deliveryItinerary.reduce[i].packages
  }` huh? that's an *interesting* code block - for one, it's probably not doing what you think, and for another, you're using `reduce` completley wrong (in fact, you're not using reduce at all, but reduce isn't an array, it's a function so `reduce[i]` will be undefined, and therefore `reduce[i].packages` will throw an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add quotes around your `name` values, because they're string literals and not JS variables. Also use an extra variable, call it `totalPackages`, to sum up all of the packages in your loop.

```js
const deliveryItinerary = [
  {  
    name: 'Doctor Allen Grant',
    address: '123 Jurassic Park Trail, Kualoa Ranch, Hawaii',
    zipcode: 96744,
    packages: 5
  },
  {
    name: 'Harry Potter',
    address: '4 Privet Drive, Manchester, England',
    zipcode: 81726,
    packages: 8
  },
  {
    name: 'Bowen Knight',
    address: '1600 Camelot Court, Liverpool, England',
    zipcode: 15064,
    packages: 2
  },
  {
    name: 'Van Helsing',
    address: '1462 Dracula\'s Castle, Valerious, Transylvania',
    zipcode: 18870,
    packages: 1
  }
];

let totalPackages = 0;
for (i = 0; i < deliveryItinerary.length; i++){
  console.log(deliveryItinerary[i].address);
  console.log(deliveryItinerary[i].packages);
  totalPackages += deliveryItinerary[i].packages;
};
console.log(totalPackages);
```